# Музыка проигрывается несколько раз

Tags: unity3d

Ошибка возникает хрен знает из-за чего.

```
    private void Click_Miss()
{
    GO_Miss.SetActive(true);
    if (!AS.isPlaying)
    {
        AS.clip = aMissClip;
        AS.Play();
    }
}
```

метод выше вызывает вызывается в Update через корутину

```
if (CurTime <= 0.64 && ClickedOn5Points == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Text_Miss());
        ClickedOn5Points = false;
    }
```

Coroutine

```
public IEnumerator Text_Miss()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
    Click_Miss();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Click_Miss_Off();
}
```

Comment: при чем проигрывается музыка два раза по одному нажатию порой

Comment: А что есть ClickedOn5Points ? и где она становится true

Comment: а это кнопка. я нажимаю на button и clickedOn5Points становится true.

Comment: Выложи полный метод Corotine

Comment: Как кнопка реализована то? и где метод Click_Miss_off

Comment: я по большей мере уверен что это из за того, что я корутину вставил в апдейт. мде. май бед

Answer (score 1):

Корутина в апдейте. Нажимая на кнопку корутина воспроизводилась несколько раз.

Comment: хотя в кнопке при срабатывание я Down = false; делал. Эх:с. На некст фрейм похоже все равно срабатывало.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html

PlayOneShot ???

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip impact;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter()
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
    }
}
```

Comment: пробовал. все равно выходило 2 раза и более порой. Это все из за апдейта. Плохой апдейт.